# MSHTML: Call a function when DOM is ready, but before javascript is evaluated

Tags: c, winapi, com, mshtml, iwebbrowser2

I'm working on a cross-platform [webview](https://github.com/zserge/webview) library that uses webkit (macos/linux) and mshtml (windows). I am now trying to give users a callback that would allow them to "inject" custom javascript code into the page once it is loaded (e.g. to wrap `console.log`, to pass initial data to the web page and so on).

My current problem is with MSHTML. If I try evaluating javascript right after I call `Navigate2` - I get errors, e.g. `GetIDsOfNames` method on `script` object fails, which is understandable because it's probably too early. I try to listen to other events, such as `DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE` or `DISPID_NAVIGATECOMPLETE2`, but that arrive too late (e.g. after the scripts on the page are executed, although before window.onload).

I wonder if there is any way to get notified when the page is loaded and DOM is parsed and scripts can be evaluated, but before they are actually evaluated?

Comment: The assumption that the DOM loads then script is executed isn't correct, for example inline scripts will execute during parsing of their <script> tags then the remainder of the tree will be parsed.

Comment: @AlexK You're right. Ideally, I would like to be able to inject JS code before any of the inline scripts are executed. Webkit has a signal when window object is cleared. It happens before any script is evaluated and is a perfect hook to prepare the JS environment.

Comment: Have you tried listening to [`DownloadComplete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768331(v=vs.85).aspx) event? I believe this is fired before the parsing stage.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the suggestion. But still, the first DownloadComplete event arrives too soon, so that `GetIDsOfNames` fail. There is another one (I only have a single html file, so that must be some favicon download) and that arrives too late, after `NavigateComplete2`. Thank you all, but so far it looks to me that there is no perfect solution.